# Aggregation and Grouping with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, aggregation

I am trying to add a column of values based on account numbers and have the result show in a new column. Also, I'm identifying the first instance of the contract account as a Unique value and the others as duplicates. 
For example:

```
Index   CA#   Duplicate?    $     $$
1      1101   True        440.4  880.80 
2      1101   False       440.4  -   
3      1102   True        440.8  440.80 
4      1103   True        441.2  441.20 
5      1106   True        442.4  1,327.20 
6      1106   False       442.4  -   
7      1106   False       442.4  -
```

My first column `'CA#'` are identifiers that I want to flag as `True(or 1)` if they're the first and only `CA#`, otherwise, I want them flagged as `False(or 0)`.
For instance, `CA# 1101 on Index 1` would receive a `True` and `CA# 1101 on Index 2` would receive a `False`.

Then I'm trying to use that True flag to sum the total that each `CA#` is linked to on the `$` column. In the `CA#1101` case, the total `$$` is `880.80`.
So far I have only got as far as trying to generate a new column that has the boolean identifier for the unique values on the CA# column, but I get only True values on the new series that my code creates and I know that is wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np

file_name= ('A:\LEO\Documents\Mock data.xlsx')
sheet_name= ('Sheet1')
data = pd.read_excel(io= file_name, sheet= sheet_name)
data.sort_values('CA#', inplace= True)
data_ltd = DataFrame(data, columns=['CA#','$'])
bool_series = data_ltd['CA'].duplicated()
data_ltd ['bool_series'] = bool_series
print(data_ltd[bool_series].head(10))
```

Comment: `duplicated()` should return `False` for the first item it sees with the unique CA#, and `True` for the rest. Is what you're looking for the inverse of this array, i.e. np.invert?

Comment: I'm actually looking to get the first unique value as True. Would you mind showing me how I need to write the syntax? I keep getting a TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~; 'float' - message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inverse of [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
~df.duplicated('CA#')

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

```
df['Duplicate?'] = ~df.duplicated('CA#')

    CA#  Duplicate?      $        $$
0  1101        True  440.4    880.80
1  1101       False  440.4         -
2  1102        True  440.8    440.80
3  1103        True  441.2    441.20
4  1106        True  442.4  1,327.20
5  1106       False  442.4         -
6  1106       False  442.4         -
```

To get your `$$` column, we can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['$$'] = df.groupby('CA#')['$'].transform('sum')
df['$$'] = np.where(df['$$'].duplicated(), '-', df['$$'])

    CA#  Duplicate?      $                  $$
0  1101        True  440.4               880.8
1  1101       False  440.4                   -
2  1102        True  440.8               440.8
3  1103        True  441.2               441.2
4  1106        True  442.4  1327.1999999999998
5  1106       False  442.4                   -
6  1106       False  442.4                   -
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I did however experienced some errors as the list of CA# instances grew larger. After some ~6k CAs the results of column $$ were inaccurate. I reworked the code and I'm posting here as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for the `Duplicated` column:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'CA#': [1101, 1101, 1102,1103, 1106, 1106, 1106]})
seen = set()
def already(x):
    global seen
    if x in seen:
        return False
    else:
        seen.add(x)
        return True

df['Duplicate'] = df['CA#'].apply(already)
df
#     CA#  Duplicate
# 0  1101       True
# 1  1101      False
# 2  1102       True
# 3  1103       True
# 4  1106       True
# 5  1106      False
# 6  1106      False
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Although I'm still curious about using some sort of the duplicated() method.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Sequence of commands alters the result, duh! This sequence worked for me:

```
#Start with sorting the values    
data_fr.sort_values(by='CA',ascending= True, inplace= True) 
#Identify duplicates    
data_fr['Unique Px']= ~data_fr.duplicated('CA') 
#Group and aggregate in a new column
data_fr['$$'] = data_fr.groupby('CA')['$'].transform('sum')
```